# How can I perform DAST on protocols other than HTTP/HTTPS

Tags: appsec, audit, tools

How can I perform DAST on protocols other than HTTP/HTTPS in case of a web application which does not have an URL but communicates with many other systems to pull or push data.

Comment: What protocols are you using ? How does your web application communicate with other systems? there's not much to go on here.

Comment: Define DAST please

Comment: DAST : Dynamic Application Security Testing

Comment: Look for "fuzzing" Tools, other than that there are not much wide spread solutions available.

Comment: Any automated fuzzing tool? I am not great at that but will try to learn for sure.